# Redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS interferes with my seo friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess to create seo friendly url and also to redirect my HTTP request to HTTPS

When i don't use HTTP to HTTPS rule, my url reads
i.e. http://www.domain.com and when some one clicks username the url changes to http://www.domain.com/username

But when i use HTTP to HTTPS rule, it interferes with the url when i click username
i.e. https://www.domain.com and when some one clicks username the url changes to https://www.domain.com/username?d=username

I would want it when i use the HTTP to HTTPS rule, and i click the username my urls to look like
i.e. https://www.domain.com and when some one clicks username the url changes to https://www.domain.com/username

the problem is the https://www.domain.com/username?d=username url

Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?d=$1


#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Move first rule to the bottom and clear your browser cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your redirects first and use L flags. Also you can consolidate the rules if you use your domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On

#redirect to https and/or www/https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?d=$1 [L]
```